# sorting integers in a arraylist of objects

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, integer

I'm starting with Java, and my problem is that I have an Arraylist of objects("Articulos", means Articles), and this object has properties (like name, price, etc...). I want to sort the Arraylist by the price of each object. Here's what I've tried.

First, I fill the Arraylist manually:

```
public static void Introducir_Articulo(){
    Articulo a=new Articulo();

    System.out.println("Codigo del articulo: "+(art.size()+1));
    if(a.codArt==0){
        a.codArt++;
    } else {
        a.codArt+=art.size();
    }
    System.out.println("Nombre del articulo: ");
    a.NombreArt=sc.next();

    System.out.println("Precio del articulo: ");
    a.precio=sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("IVA del articulo: ");
    a.iva=sc.nextInt();

    art.add(a);
}
```

Later, I tried this

```
//copying the arraylist, so I don't have to change the original
artOrdenado=new ArrayList<Articulo>(art);
System.out.println(artOrdenado);

Collections.sort(artOrdenado, new Comparator<Articulo>(){
    public int compare(Articulo uno, Articulo otro){
       return uno.getPrecio().compareTo(otro.getPrecio());
    }
});
```

but it throws an exception which says "int can not be deferenced".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do the comparision in your comparator like this:

```
Collections.sort(artOrdenado, new Comparator<Articulo>(){
    public int compare(Articulo uno, Articulo otro){
        return (uno.getPrecio() - otro.getPrecio());
    }

});
```

Or by using [Integer.compare()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare%28int,%20int%29);

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `getPrecio()` returns `int` (a primitive). You can't call methods on primitives (they're not objects). You *can* call methods on objects, however, and if `getPrecio()` returns an [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) (the object counterpart to an `int`) then you should have more success (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) for more info on this aspect of Java, called boxing)

Alternatively you can compare the ints directly in your `compare()` method (e.g. if price1 < price2, return -1 etc.)

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
return uno.getPrecio-otro.getPrecio();
```

I hope getPrecio returns the price value

Answer (score 0):

What is the Type of the returning Value of `getPrecio()`? Have you defined the behavior of `compareTo()` in this Class? If you Type is `int` use the normal Operators `>`, `<` and `==` to compare the values and return the signum you want. Or simply use:

```
Collections.sort(artOrdenado, new Comparator<Articulo>(){
    public int compare(Articulo uno, Articulo otro){
        return (uno.getPrecio() - otro.getPrecio());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to compare instead

```
public int compare(Articulo uno, Articulo otro)
{
    int comparation= (uno.getPrecio()> otro.getPrecio()) ? 1 : 0;
    if(comparation== 0)
    {
       comparation= (uno.getPrecio()== otro.getPrecio()) ? 0 : -1;
    }

return comparation;
}
```