# How to use sort an ArrayList using Comparator? The variable i'm sorting by is an int

Tags: java, sorting

I created a class called Course which have a courseID field that I want to sort by. I'm having trouble getting it to even compile. Here's part of my class:

```
class Course implements Comparable<Course> {
    private String courseName;
    private int courseID;

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    public int getCourseID() {
        return courseID;
    }

    public void setCourseID(int courseID) {
        this.courseID = courseID;
    }
}
```

Now from my understanding I need to implement how to sort it, so I start writing this:

```
class IDSorter implements Comparator<Course>{
    public int compare(Course course1, Course course2) {
        return course1.getCourseID().compareTo(course2.getCourseID()); //no good here already
    }
}
```

Compiler complains, "Cannot invoke compareTo(int) on the primitive type int"

So I can't use compareTo on primitive types.... so how would I fix this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934613/sorting-integers-in-a-arraylist-of-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to call a method on a primitive type:

```
int courseID = ...;
courseID.compareTo(...);
```

This is not possible. Instead you may use [`Integer.compare(int,int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare%28int,%20int%29):

```
int a = ...;
int b = ...;
int comparison = Integer.compare(a, b);
```

Or, in your specific case:

```
class IDSorter implements Comparator<Course>{
    public int compare(Course course1, Course course2) {
        return Integer.compare(course1.getCourseID(), course2.getCourseID());
    }
}
```

Be sure to properly handle `null` values for `course1` and `course2` if necessary.

All of the primitive wrapper types have a similar static `compare()` for this purpose.

Note, by the way, that the contracts of `Comparator.compare()` and `Comparable.compareTo()` only require that negative/0/positive values be returned (not specifically -1/0/+1), so this is also sufficient in almost all cases:

```
return course1.getCourseID() - course2.getCourseID();
```

However, if you do it that way you need special handling of edge cases due to integer overflow (maybe unlikely in your scenario). The implementation of `Integer.compare()` avoids these issues by simply [not implementing it this way](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.compare%28int,int%29):

```
public static int compare(int x, int y) {
    return (x < y) ? -1 : ((x == y) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

Comment: @JBNizet I added further edge cases then just dropped the description entirely because I didn't want to distract with those specifics.

Answer (score 4):

The contract of `compare()` is clear: it must return a negative integer is first is lower than second, a positive integer is first is bigger than second, or 0 if first is equal to second. That should be very easy for you to implement.

But you don't even have to, because Integer already has such a method:

```
return Integer.compare(first, second);
```

Comment: This is true, although the root issue and source of the compiler error is the attempt to call a method (`compareTo()`) on a primitive type (`int`).

Comment: I meant "the contract of compare(). Not the contract of compareTo(). Fixed now.

Comment: I'm glad you said that, I made the exact same error in my post.

Comment: You have made the reverse error: Comparable --> compareTo. Comparator --> compare. I used compareTo for a comparator. Your answer uses  compare, for a Comparable.